# How can I use the $matches variable outside of this function?

Tags: php, function, curl

I am trying to get the variable $matches to be usable outside of this function.  So I can use echo $matches[0][0]; or $matches[0][1]; after the function gets used in my document.  So far I haven't been able to use the matches variable outside of the function at all.

```
    function curlLink($url, $regex)
{
        include ('lib/dBug.php');
        require_once('lib/curl_http_client.php');
        $curl = &new Curl_HTTP_Client();
        //$useragent = "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)";  
        $useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0";
        $curl->set_user_agent($useragent);
        ini_set('max_execution_time','0');
        $x=0;
        $matches = array();
        while (sizeof($matches) == 0 && $x < 15) {
            $html_data = $curl->fetch_url($url);
            preg_match_all($regex, $html_data, $matches); 
            $x++;
            array_shift($matches);
        }
        if (empty($matches[0][0])) {
            echo '<img src=\"/img/bigbrokenlink.png\" /><br /><br />
            <b>Sorry, no results from your search!</b><br />';
        }
        if (!empty($matches[0][0])) {
            //return $matches; //This doesn't seem to return a usable variable...
            $dBug = new dBug ($matches);
        }
}
```

Comment: return it from the function and use it?

Comment: define "doesn't seem to return a usable variable"

Comment: What do you mean by "this doesn't seem to return a usable variable..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare 
`$matches = array();` outside of function as global variable.or `return it to some function` and use.

e.g.:

```
global $matches;
function curlLink($url, $regex)
{
    global $matches;
// implementation 
}
```

//access here `$matches;`

Answer (score 1):

Set the variable as `global` by the following example:

```
global $matches;
function curlLink($url, $regex)
{
    global $matches;
```

or return it after the call, it seems you are not returning anything right now.

```
        if (!empty($matches[0][0])) {
            //return $matches; //This doesn't seem to return a usable variable...
            $dBug = new dBug ($matches);
        }
        return $matches;
}
$returned_matches = curlLink($url, $regex);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it global, but that's probably not wanted. What you should do is:

- change the first line to `function curlLink ($url, $regex, &$matchesOut)`
- at the end of function, use `$matchesOut = $matches`
- you can now use:

`$matches = array(); curlLink(arg1, arg2, $matches); echo $matches[0];`

Comment: I'd like to try this solution, but I can't seem to get this to work.  Nor could I find documentation on using &$var in a function.

Comment: Even if you can't get it to work, do NOT use global vars. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why

Comment: Here are docs; http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.by-reference